# TypeError with exec()

Tags: python-3.x, function, typeerror

I'm trying to make a program that draws certain lines based on user input.

```
#import turtle program
#called it cassy cause I was trying to come up with a fun name for an arrow 
that they call 'classic'. I tried ok.
import turtle
cassy = turtle.Turtle()
cassy.shape('classic')

#set's the window shape, so I can give myself more room
#for reference, putting startx and y as none centers it
turtle.setup(width=1200, height=600, startx=None, starty=None)



#used to find the height of what the screen size is so I could figure out 
what it was set at.
"""print(turtle.window_width())
print(turtle.window_height())"""


#gives our wonderful circle a home (where it starts), to the right and 
middle of the box
#old code (turtle.setworldcoordinates(-20, -20, 0, 20))
cassy.hideturtle()
cassy.penup()
cassy.goto(580, 0)

#sets the turtle to be facing left
cassy.left(180)
cassy.showturtle()
cassy.pendown()

#as always, I gotta have that sweet sweet starting message.
print("Welcome to the line generator!")
print("To start, type in a letter")


#using a dictionary function so I can assign each character a "Line"
line = {
    "a" : "cassy.left(20)",
    "b" : "cassy.forward(20)",
    "c" : "cassy.right(45)",
    "d" : "cassy.right(70)",    
    "e" : "cassy.circle(10)",
    "f" : "cassy.left(15)",
    "g" : "cassy.forward(15)",
    "h" : "cassy.left(60)",
    "i" : "cassy.forward(10)",
    "j" : "cassy.forward(55)",
    "k" : "cassy.circle(50, 100)",
    "l" : "cassy.right(80)",
    "m" : "cassy.forward(35)",
    "n" : "cassy.left(75)",
    "o" : "cassy.forward(45)",
    "p" : "cassy.right(5)",
    "q" : "cassy.forward(100)",
    "r" : "cassy.right(65)",
    "s" : "cassy.forward(125)",
    "t" : "cassy.left(25)",
    "u" : "cassy.forward(150)",
    "v" : "cassy.right(95)",
    "w" : "cassy.forward(120)",
    "x" : "cassy.circle(25, 175)",
    "y" : "cassy.circle(5, 190)",
    "z" : "cassy.forward(175)",
    "0" : "cassy.right(20)",
    "1" : "cassy.forward(210)",
    "2" : "cassy.left(120)",
    "3" : "cassy.forward(115)",
    "4" : "cassy.forward(15)",
    "5" : "cassy.circle(30, 150)",
    "6" : "cassy.left(70)",
    "7" : "cassy.right(40)",
    "8" : "cassy.backward(30)",
    "9" : "cassy.backward(130)"
}

#let's the user type in letters/numbers (and only those (unless I want to         
mix things up; we'll see))
while True:
    draw = input("Type anything to draw! ")

    #if statement to make sure that they only type in numbers or letters
    if(draw.isalnum() == True):

        #I can only assume that this executes the code inside the quotes
        #but I haven't looked too deeply into what exec() does
        exec(line.get(draw))

        #this seperates each character drawn by a space, for funsies (yes I know it's a weird thing to say)
        cassy.penup()
        cassy.forward(15)
        cassy.pendown()

    #else statement in case they type in other charaters that aren't numbers or letters
    else:
        print("Please only use letters or numbers.")
```

Ok so I know it's a lot to read, but my real problem is this line of code

```
exec(line.get(draw))
```

So far the program only works when I type in 1 letter at a time. but if I try and type in more than one letter, such as the phrase "hello" it gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/73059/Final Project/Final Project funstuffs.py", line 87, in <module>
    exec(line.get(draw))
TypeError: exec() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object
```

I don't really know a lot about the function exec(), and I've been trying to look stuff up about it, this is a project and I don't really have a lot of time.

If there's any problems with it, or you don't understand what I'm trying to accomplish, please let me know. I'm sort of desperate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not really with the `exec` call, but with the value you're passing as its argument. When you do `line.get(draw)`, you lookup the value of the variable `draw` in the `line` dictionary. If that value doesn't exist (as it won't if `draw` is a multi-character string), you get `None`. Running `exec(None)` gives you the `TypeError` you're seeing.

I have several suggestions for ways to fix this issue. Which ones you'll want to follow may depend on what behavior you want from your program.

To start with, I suggest using brackets to index your dictionary, rather than the `get` method. This will change the error you get from a `TypeError` (from `exec`) to a `KeyError` from the dictionary. That's still an exception, but it at least points more accurately at the cause of the issue (the string being looked up is not in the dictionary).

The next suggestion is to check for a multi-character string before trying to look it up, and report an error to the user. You can check if `len(draw)` is equal to `1`, and only run the rest of the code if it is. I'd put this check at the same place as the current check you have for alphanumeric characters.

Here's what those two fixes would look like together:

```
while True:
    draw = input("Type anything to draw! ")

    if draw.isalnum() and len(draw) == 1:  # check length, "== True" and parens were unneeded
        exec(line[draw])  # use indexing instead of "get" to generate better exception types

    else:
        print("Please only enter a single letter or number at a time.")
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow longer inputs (with each character in the input being handled separately), you could change your code to loop over the characters rather than trying to deal with them all at once. That would look something like this:

```
while True:
    draw = input("Type anything to draw! ")

    if draw.isalnum():  # no length check needed in this version

        for character in draw:   # loop over characters
            exec(line[character])

            cassy.penup()     # it's not clear if you want these lines inside the inner loop
            cassy.forward(15) # if not, you can unindent them one level
            cassy.pendown()

    else:
        print("Please only use letters or numbers.")
```

While this should work, using `exec` is usually a bad way to write code. A better approach would be to put functions (or other callable objects) into your dictionary, and then call the value you get back from the indexing. You can create anonymous functions using the `lambda` keyword. Lambda functions have some limits, but they're good enough for our needs. Here's how your could would look using lambdas in the dictionary:

```
line = {
    "a" : lambda: cassy.left(20),
    "b" : lambda: cassy.forward(20),
    "c" : lambda: cassy.right(45),
    "d" : lambda: cassy.right(70),    
    "e" : lambda: cassy.circle(10),
    "f" : lambda: cassy.left(15),
    "g" : lambda: cassy.forward(15),
    "h" : lambda: cassy.left(60),
    "i" : lambda: cassy.forward(10),
    "j" : lambda: cassy.forward(55),
    "k" : lambda: cassy.circle(50, 100),
    "l" : lambda: cassy.right(80),
    "m" : lambda: cassy.forward(35),
    "n" : lambda: cassy.left(75),
    "o" : lambda: cassy.forward(45),
    "p" : lambda: cassy.right(5),
    "q" : lambda: cassy.forward(100),
    "r" : lambda: cassy.right(65),
    "s" : lambda: cassy.forward(125),
    "t" : lambda: cassy.left(25),
    "u" : lambda: cassy.forward(150),
    "v" : lambda: cassy.right(95),
    "w" : lambda: cassy.forward(120),
    "x" : lambda: cassy.circle(25, 175),
    "y" : lambda: cassy.circle(5, 190),
    "z" : lambda: cassy.forward(175),
    "0" : lambda: cassy.right(20),
    "1" : lambda: cassy.forward(210),
    "2" : lambda: cassy.left(120),
    "3" : lambda: cassy.forward(115),
    "4" : lambda: cassy.forward(15),
    "5" : lambda: cassy.circle(30, 150),
    "6" : lambda: cassy.left(70),
    "7" : lambda: cassy.right(40),
    "8" : lambda: cassy.backward(30),
    "9" : lambda: cassy.backward(130)
}

while True:
    draw = input("Type anything to draw! ")

    if(draw.isalnum() == True):

        for character in draw:   # loop over characters
            line[character]()    # call the value looked up in the dict

            cassy.penup()   # it's not clear if you want these lines inside the inner loop
            cassy.forward(15) # if not, you can unindent them one level
            cassy.pendown()

    else:
        print("Please only use letters or numbers.")
```

There are several other ways you could make the callables, such as using `functools.partial` to bind the turtle methods and their arguments together.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and the help, my project is running smoothly now.